# Membership.CreateUser and Entity Framework how to delete user when is some error

Tags: c#, asp.net-membership

First step:

```
some logic...
var user = Membership.CreateUser("test@test.com", "asddfasdf!fsdf");
some logic woth ERROR..
```

So user should not be created because of an error. I am using `transaction.Dispose();`

Second step:

```
var user = Membership.CreateUser("test@test.com", "gfdgd!fsdf");
```

throw exception

> System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateUserException was unhandled by
>   user code   HResult=-2146233088   Message=The username is already in
>   use.   Source=System.Web   StackTrace:

I am using `ENTITY framework` so why was user created in first step. All other relevant data were not inserted, just user was created. Why?

How to prevent create user with excpetion

Comment: Why shouldn't the user be created? `Membership` uses a different connection from whatever connection your code is using. If you want to delete the user in response to some other logic, use Membership.DeleteUser

Comment: but why manually to delete it? If I am using one DBContext for whole request and there is an error somewhere in the code then rollback should be triggered or not?

Comment: Not. Entity Framework is just one DB access method, it doesn't control all connections to a database. Even if ASP.NET Membership used EF (it doesn't, it predates EF by almost a decade), it *wouldn't* use the same connection. If you wanted a global transaction, you should use TransactionScope. That would require the use of DTC though, since multiple DB connections are involved

Comment: huh what is then workaround. To catch exception?

Comment: There is no problem in EF or Membership that requires a workaround. You have to decide what you want to do in your code. I'd assume you *already* catch exceptions so you can log them. Failing to create a user because of an exception is definitely something that would need logging. You can delete the user in that exception handler as well

Comment: BTW keeping a database transaction open for a long time "just in case" or for convenience is not a good design. It keeps connections open for longer than needed and results in database conflicts, locks and delays. It's a sure way to kill a web site's performance